# C++ EnumWindows, store the list in a string array

Tags: c++, string, winapi, dynamic-arrays

I'm new on C++, I started learning just a couple of weeks ago.
At the moment I'm trying to store the title of all windows with a specific class name in a dynamic string array.
Until now I did it defining LIST as a global variable, but I'd like do use a local one and pass it to the EnumWindows function.

```
string* LIST=new string[10];
int N;

int main(){
     N=0;
     EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)CreateList,0);
     for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
         cout << LIST[i]<< endl;
     }
     return 0
}

BOOL CreateList(HWND hWnd, long lParam){
   char TitleArray[255], ClassArray[255];
   GetWindowText(hWnd,TitleArray,254);
   GetClassName(hWnd,ClassArray,254);
   string ClassString=ClassArray;
   string TitleString=TitleArray;
   if (ClassString=="CLASS_NAME"){
       LIST[N]=TitleString;
       N++;
   }
   return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you have to cast a callback proc (1st param to `EnumWindows`) then you have declared it incorrectly.

Comment: Why don't you store your strings in a `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: See also the `push_back` method of `std::vector`.

Comment: Before posting your next question you should go through [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Finally, if you are sure your question fits the rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a useful, well formed and on-topic question.

Comment: You are going to need to learn not to respond to the compiler telling you that you made a mistake by suppressing it with a cast and telling it that you know better.

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter to [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) is documented as:

> An application-defined value to be passed to the callback function.

Since you need to pass an application-defined value to your callback function, simply do so, e.g.:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> windowTitles;
    ::EnumWindows(&CreateList, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&windowTitles));
    // ...
}
```

To retrieve a pointer to the window titles container in the callback, the *lParam* argument needs to have its type reinstated:

```
BOOL CALLBACK CreateList(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    std::vector<std::string>& windowTitles =
        *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::string>*>(lParam);
    // Use windowTitles, e.g. windowTitles.push_back(TitleString);
    // ...
}
```

Take special note, that your `CreateList` signature is wrong. It's missing both a calling convention (`CALLBACK`) as well as using the wrong type for the second argument (`long` is 32 bits wide even in 64-bit Windows). You cannot safely pass a pointer using a parameter of type `long`, not even in 32-bit Windows (`long` is signed). Have the compiler help you out, by removing the C-style cast in your `EnumWindows` call.